# Ansible: use host address of hosts.ini in playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have to do a POST request with ansible.

My `hosts.ini` file is:

```
[workers]
worker1 ansible_host=111.111.111.111 
worker2 ansible_host=222.222.222.222
```

The url I have to connect to needs the ip address of worker1, so I wrote my playbook as:

```
- hosts: worker1

  tasks:
  - name: inizialize worker                                          
    uri:
      url: "http://{{ worker1 }}:8080/xxx/yyy"
      method: POST
      user: admin
      password: password
      force_basic_auth: yes
      return_content: yes
      body: "field=myfield"
```

But running it, I get:

> the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'worker1' is undefined

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a variable named `worker1` defined.

If you wanted to replace the value with `111.111.111.111`, you should use [magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts):

```
url: "http://{{ hostvars['worker1']['ansible_host'] }}:8080/xxx/yyy"
```

but considering your whole play, you might as well wanted:

```
url: "http://{{ ansible_host }}:8080/xxx/yyy"
```

---

Mind that your inventory file defines a host group named `workers` and your play refers to a host group named `worker1` -- this makes no sense altogether.